# how to consume .svc file

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have got url for svc file. For example `https://Myservicelocation/UserService.svc`.

Now i tried to create asp.net web application in visual studio and added this url using "Add service reference". When i put this url and then click go i get error

> The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
>       Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://Myservicelocation/UserService.svc'.
>       Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service https://Myservicelocation/UserService.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
>       The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
>       If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Do you have the WSDL file?

Comment: @Coder1409 yes i have. So looks like i have to use wsdl instead of svc. am i correct?

Comment: Try copying your WSDL , paste it in a .WSDL file , add a service reference to this file and try again , if the problem persists use channel factory instead if you have the contract definition of your service

Comment: @Coder1409 it works when i add .wsdl while adding service reference. So it doesnt work with using .svc?

Comment: I don't how you have implemented your service nor the authorization you have over the server , it can be anything , try add ?wsdl after .svc , it should work

Comment: @coder1409 what u mean try add wsdl after svc?

Comment: In your URL , use it like https://server/service.svc?wsdl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75734/discussion-between-happy-and-coder1409).

Comment: @Coder1409 this also doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Google says..

> Probably a mismatch in the client/server bindings, where the message version in the service uses SOAP 1.1 (which expects application/soap+xml) and the version in the client uses SOAP 1.2 (which sends text/xml). WSHttpBinding uses SOAP 1.2, BasicHttpBinding uses SOAP 1.1.

Align your bindings accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Try `https://Myservicelocation/UserService.svc?wsdl` link.

Comment: It did not work. I got this error.
```Error loading [http://partners.qa.gfs.dom/Account/LogOn]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed```